# Levenshtein Distance for a List of Thousands of Similar Entries of Cryptocurrencies

Tags: c#, arrays, levenshtein-distance, querying

I have a list of over a thousand different cryptocurrencies alphabetized. The issue is here if a user queries for, say, "BTC" they will get BTCA (Bitair) out of the list, since THAT comes before Bitcoin. Alternatively, typing Bitcoin will give you "AntiBitcoin" instead, since THAT comes before Bitcoin. Originally, this occurred because I used `.Contains()` which is just not correct, so now I switched to Levenshtein for delimination.

I am setting up a simple loop like this:

```
foreach (String s in crypto.currencies)
{
    if (Crypto.LevenshteinDistance(s,currency) <= (Stuck on the right way to do this now))
    {
        //foo
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s + " is not a match. Continuing.");
}
```

But I am very stuck on how I should actually go upon getting the proper item the user wants. It may seem completely dumb, what I am trying to do, but it is imperative I can properly query through this list (plus, I had typed it out by hand, ouch)

Comment: I'm not sure how you are displaying results. But most search UI works by showing the top few results for a search term. Why not display all coins which contain the given search string instead of the "single best match"? Even better, then sort those results by the current market cap of the search results by getting to coinmarketcap or similar API.

Comment: I only need display one. That is the problem :(

Comment: The ideal Levenshtein distance is 0 for perfect match. The closer to 0 the better. If that does not result in a good match you have to adjust the weights that define how much points an insertion, deletion, ... is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could order the list on the Levenshtein distance from the target currency, and pick the top one:

```
var closestMatch = crypto.currencies
    .OrderBy(s => Crypto.LevenshteinDistance(s, currency))
    .First();
```

Comment: That worked flawlessly. Thank you! I'd upvote you, but, I have but 1 rep :(